# Magento add upload image field in product custom options

Tags: image, magento, image-uploading

I want to add image upload option from Magento admin product custom options section.

Please suggest me how can i do this. thanks[image]

Edit

[image]

Comment: It means, would u like to have an option for image upload in the fronend?

Comment: no from the backend..

Comment: @Anx till now no...do you have any idea?